# java вызывает не тот метод

Tags: java, ооп

Задача: Определить класс Дробь (*Rational*) в виде пары (*num*, *den*). 
Класс должен содержать несколько конструкторов. Реализовать методы для сложения, вычитания, умножения, деления и сокращения дробей. Создать массив объектов и передать его в статический метод, который возвращает сумму дробей.

Определить класс Дробь с выделенной целой частью (*RationalInt*) в виде тройки (*intpart*, *num*, *den*) наследованием класса *Rational*. Переопределить при необходимости методы суперкласса. Создать массив объектов класса *Rational*, заполнить его объектами классов *Rational* и *RalionalInt* и передать его в статический метод, который возвращает сумму этих дробей.
Ошибка в массиве в классе *RationalRunner*
исходный код с классом *Rational* все в порядке

```
/*рациональное число*/

public class Rational {
    private int n, d;

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(int d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public Rational(int n, int d) {
        this.n = n;
        this.d = d;
        if (n != 0)
            reduction();
        else
            this.d = 1;
    }

    public Rational(Rational b) {
        this.d=b.d;
        this.n=b.n;
    }
    public Rational(Rationalint b){
        this.d=b.getD();
        this.n=b.getIntPart()*b.getN();
    }
    public void reduction() {
        int t = nod(n, d);
        n /= t;
        d /= t;
    }

    private int nod(int a, int b) {
        while (a != b) {
            if (a > b)
                a -= b;
            else
                b -= a;
        }
        return a;

    }

    public Rational sum(Rational b) {
        int den = nok(d, b.getD());
        int num = n * den / d + b.getN() * den / b.getD();
        return new Rational(num, den);
    }

    protected int nok(int a, int b) {
        return a * b / nod(a, b);
    }

    public void write() {
        System.out.println(n + "/" + d);
    }

    public static Rational sumArray(Rational[] x) {
        Rational s = new Rational(0, 1);
        for (Rational elem : x) {
            s=s.sum(elem);
        }
        return s;
    }

}

/*дробь с целой частью*/ 
public class Rationalint extends Rational {
    private int intPart;

    public int getIntPart() {
        return intPart;
    }

    public void setIntPart(int intPart) {
        this.intPart = intPart;
    }

    public Rationalint(int c, int n, int d) {
        super(n, d);
        intPart = c;
        intPart += n / d;
        setN(n % d);
        if (getN() == getD()) {
            intPart++;
            setN(0);
            setD(1);
        }
    }
    public Rationalint(Rational b){
        this(0,b.getN(),b.getD());
    }


    public void write() {
        System.out.println("{" + intPart + "}" + getN() + "/" + getD());
    }


    public Rationalint sum(Rationalint b) {// почему то не используется в 
    //   вычислениях массива
        int c = this.intPart + b.intPart;
        int den = nok(getD(), b.getD());
        int num = getN() * den / getD() + b.getN() * den / b.getD();
        return new Rationalint(c, num, den);
    }

    public Rationalint sum(Rational b) {
        int c = this.intPart;
        int den = nok(getD(), b.getD());
        int num = getN() * den / getD() + b.getN() * den / b.getD();
        return new Rationalint(c, num, den);

    }

    public static  Rationalint sumArray(Rational[] x) {

        Rationalint s = new Rationalint(0, 0, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            s = (Rationalint)s.sum(x[i]);
        }
        return s;
    }

}

public class RationalRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rational[] arr = new Rational[] {  new Rational(3, 1),
                new Rationalint(1,1, 4) };
        Rational s = Rationalint.sumArray(arr);
    введите сюда код

//Ошибка работает не правильно складывает дроби не учитывая целую часть. хотя 
//метод sum перегружен для любого варианта

        s.write();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `public Rationalint sum(Rationalint b)` не вызывается, т.к. выбор перегруженного (overload) метода осуществляется на этапе компиляции, а не во время выполнения, как с переопределением (override). Тип аргумента `x[i]` известный компилятору - `Rational`.

Что вам с этим делать - вопрос. Я бы предложил ограничить нововведения в классе `Rationalint` параметром конструктора (который бы сразу плюсовал в числитель, домножив на знаменатель) и переопределением `write()` (чтобы красиво выводить целую часть). Заодно сохранится коммутативность сложения: сейчас у вас

```
    Rational a = new Rational( 1, 2 );
    Rational b = new Rationalint(1, 1, 2);

    a.sum( b ).write();
    b.sum( a ).write();
```

выводит

```
    1/1
    {2}0/1
```

Comment: Также можно использовать `instanceof` и явно задавать вызываемый метод. Однако это не лучшее решение. Лучше поменять порядок наследования. Ведь класс `Double` не наследуется от класса `Integer`.